# How can I tell if my Excellon drill file is in number format 2.4?

Tags: pcb-fabrication

Sierra Circuits has a "No Touch," *no minimum* board fabrication service.
Their data requirements for that service are:

```
Units = Inch
Tool units = Inch
Coordinate = Absolute
Zeros omitted = Trailing
Number Format = 2.4
```

I have designed my board in OsmondPCB, and this is what the header of the drill file looks like, as well as the beginning of the file:

```
M48
FMAT,2
INCH,LZ
T1C0.1250
T2C0.0200
T3C0.0350
% 

T1
X0025Y078125
X0025Y005
X145Y005
X145Y078125
T2
X021875Y053125
X131875Y053125
X141875Y053125
X141875Y005625
X131875Y005625 ...
```

Can anyone tell me if I meet their data requirements?

Comment: "Can anyone tell me..." - I expect that Sierra Circuits can ;) Maybe their [PCB DFM Tool](https://www.protoexpress.com/tools/pcb-dfm-tool/) would help, as it includes drill checks.

Comment: Check if you have a 1/8 inch hole at coordinates X=0.25 Y=0.5 inch.

Comment: I believe they mean that numbers without a decimal point are understood to be 2 digits in front and 4 behind: ie, `X021875Y053125` ( from your file) means X=2.1875 and Y=5.3125, and they interpret those as inches.

Comment: Thanks, everyone! I figured it out on my own. But, I appreciate the several quick responses. Had to fire up my desktop computer... As I said above, this site doesn't work on my iPad, which makes it a bit inconvenient.